# C'# Checking if an Ajax call c# side

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller

I have some code below so that when a user calls a method in an mvc controller it does some checks to see if it is an Ajax call or not. If Ajax it returns a json response else it returns a url string (Security page). When I run in visual studio the code works perfectly so it recognises the call is an ajax call but on a production server variable "isAjax" is set to false. Is there any reason why it would work locally in visual (local iis) but not on a server?

```
var isAjax = (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest") ||
                             ((filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers != null) &&
                             (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest"));
```

On the network tab in the browser it shows that it is being passed (image below)

[Network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVw5n.png)

Comment: The solution is to add that header in your javascript when you call `fetch`. I think only JQuery does it automatically.

Comment: Thanks Poul. Included an image now that shows that it is being passed but for some reason C# server side code does not pick this up. Apparently it isn't case sensitive and have tried lowercase, uppercase e.t.c.

Comment: Look at the `Status code`, it's 403 = `Forbidden`. That's probably the real reason for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult GetData()
{
  if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        return RedirectToAction("AjaxRequest");
  else
        return RedirectToAction("NonAjaxRequest");
}
```

Instead of checking the headers you can check the current request at controller level.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX calls will have a header named **X-Requested-With**, and the value will be **XMLHttpRequest**. So you can check like this:

```
bool isAjaxRequest = request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest";
```

Otherwise you can use the **System.Web.MVC** reference and use the function.

```
bool isAjaxRequest = Request.IsAjaxRequest();
```